# Display each character in a different color Angular JS

Tags: html, angularjs

I would like to display each character in a word with different color in Angular JS. i tried using `<span>` tag in js file but html is not parsing it. Let me know the best way i can do it.  `<span style="color: red">T</span>`

Comment: what does *"i tried using tag in js file but html is not parsing it."* mean?  can you show the code for what isn't working?

Comment: @AjeetShah, don't answer a question by editing the question to include the answer.

Comment: @DanielBeck he didn't, he simply edited the question and added a few backticks so that the code the OP had placed would show up.  You have rolled back a valid edit....

Comment: @AjeetShah Deepest apologies, I misread the edit history!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest way would probably be to split the word into different spans containing just one letter:

```
let letters = word.split('')
             .map(letter => `<span color="your_color">${letter}</span>`)
```